# Logging in users to OneDrive

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, windows, onedrive

I want to check whether a user is already logged in to OneDrive and, if not, allow them to log in. I first tried this with a JS/HTML project. Then with a C#/XAML project.

I looked at the C#/XAML OneDrive code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631823.aspx) and it seemed easier to follow, so I created a project with that, only to get the error:

```
error CS0103: The name 'updateUI' does not exist in the current context
```

- The JS/HTML project problem (seen below this line) was solved, but I want to know if anyone knows how to solve the C# error.

---

For the JS/HTML project I followed the code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631820.aspx) added it in the default.js file:

```
WL.init({ scope: ["wl.signin", "wl.skydrive"] }).then(
    function (result) {
        if (result.status == "connected") {
            //display to the user, that they are connected
            }
        else {
            // Display the sign-in button.
            connectButton.style.display = "block";
            connectButton.onclick = function () {
                WL.login({
                    scope: ["wl.signin", "wl.skydrive"]
                        }).then(
                            function (result) {
                                if (result.status == "connected") {
                                    // Don't display the sign-in button.
                                    connectButton.style.display = "none";
                                    //display to the user, that they are connected
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    };
                }
            });
```

and included this is the default.html header:

```
<script src="///LiveSDKHTML/js/wl.js"></script>
```

and this in the default.html body:

```
<button id="connectButton" style="display:none">
Connect with a Microsoft account</button>
```

However, after running the app, nothing seems to happen. I even changed the JavaScript to this just to make sure the function was being called correctly, but nothing happens. No background change (and yes I have jQuery included and it works outside the WL.init call):

```
WL.init({ scope: ["wl.signin", "wl.skydrive"] }).then(
        function (result) {
            if (result.status == "connected") {
                $('body').css('background-clor', 'blue');
            }
            else {
                $('body').css('background-clor', 'red');
            }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

Put some console.log or alerts in your code. See if you get any returns. If you don't, you're probably missing something. 
Try playing with the session functions too ( WL.getSession ).

For example I've read about Live SDK v5.6 and noticed this:
The Live SDK must be installed on your machine.

Comment: Huh, I thought I had installed the Live SDK already. Anyways, I installed it again and restarted Visual Studio and the JS/HTML version actually worked. However, I still get the error for the C#/XAML project

Comment: We're on to something.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't recognize the function 'updateUI', but I don't know what library I should include, if any